# Why composer.phar needs to be updated after 60 days?

Tags: composer-php

I just want to understand that, why the composer.phar file needs to be updated after 60 days?

Comment: it _should_ be updated once in a while.. like everything else. it's a project in active development, and it was marked stable just recently

Comment: @Federico But, why after 60 days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why composer.phar needs to be updated after 60 days?

Composer doesn't **need** to be updated after 60 days. But an update is **recommended** after that time!

> Why 60 days?

I can't speak for the core developers on this decision, so i can only give you an educated guess:

Composer used a shorter frequency for recommending updates during its development and alpha stages. The former message was  `Warning: This development build of composer is over 30 days old. It is recommended to update...`.
Users were recommended to pull updates in a short frequency to stay on the latest, bleeding-edge version. A short update frequency allows that users report bugs and issues quickly back to the project. This results in a very fast feedback and development cycle with fast roll-outs of new versions to address urgent issues.

Now, that Composer is released as stable the time was increased to 60 days, because (i guess) a very fast feedback cycle is no longer needed. This reflects that the project is no longer in a pre-release/alpha development mode, but has stabilized. Stats might lie, but you might also take a look at their issue tracker where you find an massive amount of closed tickets and only a few open ones: 120 open to 3,356 closed issues (02-06-2016).